# Viewport Denoising Doesn't Load

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

So I'm currently trying to enable viewport denoising automatic using Cycles in Blender 2.93, but whenever I do the viewport turns grey and it doesn't load (it stays stuck on "loading render kemels). When I go to uncheck the denoising Blender crashes. I have GPU Compute enabled as the renderer and am using the CUDA settings for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

Here is what the viewport looks like when I enable denoising:
[image]

(there is a scene and the lighting is an HDRI but you can't see it in the render)

Here is the .blend file: [image]

I'm not sure what to do and would really appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)"

You usually only have to do this once, and it can take quite a while. Either turn on viewport render and wait, or render one frame with Optix denoiser and wait for that.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the quick reply! I had been waiting for the render a minute or two before and just kept thinking "there's no way people wait this long each time they want to see it in rendered mode" but I didn't know you only had to do that once. Thanks so much man!